# Javascript Strategy Design Pattern issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am following this gist for a strategy design pattern.
https://gist.github.com/Integralist/5736427

I implemented this a few months ago and the chrome extension did not throw any errors when I implemented it but now its throwing a

"Uncaught TypeError: this.strategy is not a function"

```
var MessageHandling = function(strategy) {
    this.strategy = strategy;
};
MessageHandling.prototype.greet = function() {
    return this.strategy();
};
```

its strange because the functions that rely on this code still run but some other code that does not rely on it is limited.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: sounds like you are not passing a function to MessageHandling

Comment: Do you mean that my other code is not being passed correctly to MessageHandling?

Comment: we need to see all of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly about the object you create from MessageHandling, if you pass the right function while creating the object it should always work.

```
var MessageHandling = function(strategy) {
    this.strategy = strategy;
};
MessageHandling.prototype.greet = function() {
    return this.strategy();
};
var m = new MessageHandling(function(){console.log('hello');});
m.greet();
```

The above code will always work but if you instantiate the MessageHandling with passing a parameter which is not a function or not passing a parameter at all then it will complain that this.strategy is not a function. So you need to make sure you pass the right function to MessageHandling while creating its object.

Comment: Thanks! this was a great help. I commented out some some old MessageHandling strategies that were suspect if they were actually passing functions to the Handler in their current state. Life saver!

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your full code here in order for someone to figure out the problem. But from the exception text, it looks like you are passing an undefined strategy or a "variable that is not a function" to the constructor. The following sample will give the same `"Uncaught TypeError: this.strategy is not a function` exception:

```
// This is the Greeter constructor.
var Greeter = function(strategy) {
    this.strategy = strategy;  
};

// Greeter provides a greet function that is going to
// greet people using the Strategy passed to the constructor.
Greeter.prototype.greet = function() {
  return this.strategy();
};

// Here are a couple of Strategies to use with our Greeter.
var politeGreetingStrategy = function() {
 console.log("Hello."); 
};

var friendlyGreetingStrategy = function() {
  console.log("Hey!");
};

var boredGreetingStrategy = function() {
  console.log("sup.");
};

var undefinedStrategy; //Not a function variable

// Let's use these strategies!
var politeGreeter   = new Greeter(politeGreetingStrategy);
var friendlyGreeter = new Greeter(friendlyGreetingStrategy);
var boredGreeter    = new Greeter(boredGreetingStrategy);
var wrongGreeter = new Greeter(undefinedStrategy); //No such strategy defined

politeGreeter.greet();   //=> Hello.
friendlyGreeter.greet(); //=> Hey!
boredGreeter.greet();    //=> sup.
wrongGreeter.greet();   //-> uncaught type
```